# one link on navbar to the right side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Log in button on the right side of navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Klokkebutikk</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php?kategori=1">Herre</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?kategori=2">Dame</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?kategori=3">Barn</a></li>
        <li><a href="ny.php">Logg inn</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the link in another `ul` below and use the `pull-right` class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Klokkebutikk</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php?kategori=1">Herre</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?kategori=2">Dame</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?kategori=3">Barn</a></li>
    </ul>
    //add here
    <ul class="pull-right nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="ny.php">Logg inn</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Example here - http://www.bootply.com/NJ0UqYdKsh